# TYPO3 Extension in Typoscript COA does not recognize Default Controller

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am trying to override a Marker within my Typoscript with content rendered by my custom created extension.

As far as I know It should work like this (Where `MENU_PRODUKT_CATEGORIES`) is my Marker:

```
 MENU_PRODUKT_CATEGORIES = COA
        MENU_PRODUKT_CATEGORIES {
            10 = USER
            10 {
                userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
                extensionName = MoTimeProducts
                pluginName = Products
                vendorName = products
                controller = Category
                action = parentList
            }
        }
```

The extensionName and related configurations also seem correct to me. When I `var_dump()` my ext_localconf.php configuratin this is displayed:

My first Parameter where MoTimeProducts is my extensionName and products my vendorName. Is this correct?

```
MoTimeProducts.products
```

The second Parameter should be the pluginName and seems ok, too.

```
Products
```

This is how my complete ext_localconf configuration looks like:

```
    <?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MoTimeProducts.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Products',
    array(
        'Category' => 'list, parentList',
        'Product' => 'list, show, filter, ajaxFilter, refList',
        'Formular' => 'display'
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Category' => '',
        'Product' => 'ajaxFilter, list',
        'Formular' => 'display'
    )
);
```

My Controller and Action configuration seems fine also. Below my action within the CategoryController

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function parentListAction() {
    $this->view->assign('categories', $currentCategory = $this->categoryRepository->getHighestLevelCategories($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid));
}
```

I also have a flex form for the Backend configuration and inserting plugins could this also be a reason?

Thx for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow it was

```
MENU_PRODUKT_CATEGORIES = COA
            MENU_PRODUKT_CATEGORIES {
                10 = USER
                10 {
                    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
                    pluginName = Products
                    extensionName = Products
                    vendorName = MoTimeProducts
                    controller = Category
                    action = list
                    switchableControllerActions {
                        Category {
                            1 = parentList
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Where vendorName with a combination of lowercased plugin name is the first paramater for the plugin configuration.

Edit: Turns out it is very bad practice to have the same name for the plugin/extension which can lead to confusion and errors. One should avoid doing it like I did at all cost!